# Natural full outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

There are three relations (t1, t2, t3):

```
t1
-----------
 a  | b

 1  | 2
----------- 

t2
------------
  b  |  c

  2  | 3
------------

t3
-------------
  a  |  c

  4  |  5
-------------
```

The query is:

```
select * from t1 natural full outer join (t2 natural full outer join t3);
```

The result of `select * from t2 natural full outer join t3` is:

```
-----------------
  a  |  b  |  c

     | 2   | 3

  4  |     | 5
------------------
```

then I tried:

`select *  from t1 natural full outer join (result)`

```
    t1             result
-----------      -----------------
 a  | b           a    |  b  | c

 1  | 2                | 2   | 3

                    4  |     | 5
                 ------------------
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
--------------------------
   a    |  b  |  c

   1    |  2  | 3

  4     |     | 5
```

But I don't know why the sql query give:

```
 a | b | c 

 4 |   | 5
   | 2 | 3
 1 | 2 |
```

Comment: Full outer join doesn't exist in mysql. If you want to emulate it, check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```
select *
from t1 natural full outer join
     result
```

Is equivalent to:

```
select *
from t1 full outer join
     result
     on t1.a = result.a and t1.b = result.b;
```

The `natural` join looks at *all* the fields in common, not just one.  There are no rows that match, which is why you are getting three rows of results.

You seem to want:

```
select *
from t1 full outer join
     result
     on t1.b = result.b;
```

In general, it is better to avoid `natural` join's, because they "hide" information about what the query is doing and can readily lead to mistakes/unexpected results as you experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you knows how `FULL OUTER JOIN` works.

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` combines the results of both left and right outer joins and **returns all (matched or unmatched)** rows from the tables on both sides of the join clause.

So, if you want this result:

```
--------------------------
   a    |  b  |  c

   1    |  2  | 3

   4    |     | 5
```

With these tables:

```
    t1             result
-----------      -----------------
 a  | b           a    |  b  | c

 1  | 2                | 2   | 3

                    4  |     | 5
```

You should do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 natural RIGHT JOIN (result) res ON t1.b = res.b
```

because you must specify with which column have to be joined.